# What is hibernate and n-hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, visual-studio-2008, nhibernate-mapping, asp.net-3.5

What is hibernate and n-hibernate? can I use it in Visual Studio 2008 for C# Web Application development ? Pls Suggest me... I am newer to asp.net web application Developement. Just I heard about Hibernate.. How can i learn and implement in easy way....

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 7):

Yes, You can implement NHibernate Application in VS2008 using C#. You need to download a Nhibernate SDK from http://nhforge.org/ and need to install it in your system.

Below I mentioned a brief intorduction of **Hibernate** and **NHibernate**.

**Hibernate:**

Hibernate is an object-relational mapping (ORM) library for the Java language, providing a framework for mapping an object-oriented domain model to a traditional relational database. Hibernate solves object-relational impedance mismatch problems by replacing direct persistence-related database accesses with high-level object handling functions.

Hibernate is free software that is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License.

Hibernates primary feature is mapping from Java classes to database tables (and from Java data types to SQL data types). Hibernate also provides data query and retrieval facilities. It also generates the SQL calls and attempts to relieve the developer from manual result set handling and object conversion and keep the application portable to all supported SQL databases with little performance overhead.

For more details please visit: http://www.hibernate.org/

**NHibernate:**

NHibernate is an object-relational mapping (ORM) solution for the Microsoft .NET platform: it provides a framework for mapping an object-oriented domain model to a traditional relational database. Its purpose is to relieve the developer from a significant portion of relational data persistence-related programming tasks. NHibernate is free as open source software that is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License. NHibernate is a port of the popular Java O/R mapper Hibernate to .NET.

For more details please visit: http://nhforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

They're frameworks for object relational mapping, working with relational database management systems. Hibernate is the java based version, nHibernate is the .Net equivalent. They enable you to work with databases programmatically in a way that's fairly well decoupled from vendor specifics, so, once you've told it which dialect it's using, you don't have to do anything different depending on whether you're on MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Relational Persistence for Java and .Net](http://www.hibernate.org/), I would recommend the [Documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/docs.html) too